# masonry-brick media-item blocks tooltips

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following is in a Rails 3 application:

```
<i class="fa fa-hourglass-half has-tooltip info-icon-small" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" data-original-title="This tooltip shows up as expected."></i>
<ul class="masonry media-grid" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <li class="masonry-brick media-item">
        <h3>This text shows up</h3>
        <i class="fa fa-hourglass-half has-tooltip info-icon-small" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" data-original-title="No sign of this tooltip."></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the page is viewed the first icon shows up with a working tooltip but the second icon's tooltip is never visible. Removing `class="masonry-bick media-item"` from each `<li>` element causes the tooltips to show up whilst, of course, making a mess of the layout.

Does anyone know why this happens, or any means of allowing the tooltips to display within the `<li class="masonry-brick media-item">` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No-one seems to know a way to fix this and I couldn't either, but I did make use of a workaround to display the tooltips. This was to remove the tooltips from the icons and concatenate them into the `<li>` element, thus:

```
<li class="masonry-brick media-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="First tooltip. &#13;Second tooltip.">
```

This isn't great but at least the required messages are displayed when the mouse moves over the element containing the icons.